# revolution surface about an slanted line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I find the equation of the revolution surface that is spanned when the curve $y=x^2  ,z=0$  is spinned around $y=x$ ?

Is there any general method for finding the equation of the revolution surface that is spanned when a curve $y=f(x),z=0$  is spinned around an oblique line $ax+by+c=0\ ; \ a,b\not=0$ ?

Thanks for your idaes.

Comment: Are you happy with a parametric equation for the resulting surface of revolution?

Comment: I want both of them. Cartesian and parametric equations.

Comment: Here's a plan: 1) Rotate the $xy$-plane in such a way that the line $x=y$ becomes the $x$-axis. 2) Revolve about that $x$-axes. 3) Rotate back. The rotations amount to linear substitutions, so this should not prove to be too difficult. The same method can be applied to any other line - only those linear substitutions will be a tad messier.

Comment: I think that Your (2) should be : Write curve $y=f(x)$ in the new plane $XoY$ and then revolve $Y=f(X)$ about that $X$-axis.